# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:""). Expected elements are

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

You can find a lot of questions like this in this site but none has solved my issue.

This is my XML :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<lookupInstances xmlns='http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1' name='LKIMGR'>
<lookupParameters>
<lookupParameter name='businessArea'>PQAA</lookupParameter>
<lookupParameter name='MEMBERNUMBER'>ANTHONY1900</lookupParameter>
</lookupParameters>
</lookupInstances>
```

I have created the Jaxb class using the XJC compiler and the file created is as :

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2015.01.13 at 12:15:41 PM IST 
//


package com.dsths.ga.awd.main;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="lookupParameters">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element name="lookupParameter">
 *                     &lt;complexType>
 *                       &lt;complexContent>
 *                         &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                           &lt;attribute name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *                         &lt;/restriction>
 *                       &lt;/complexContent>
 *                     &lt;/complexType>
 *                   &lt;/element>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "lookupParameters"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "lookupInstances")
public class LookupInstances {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected LookupInstances.LookupParameters lookupParameters;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String name;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the lookupParameters property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link LookupInstances.LookupParameters }
     *     
     */
    public LookupInstances.LookupParameters getLookupParameters() {
        return lookupParameters;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the lookupParameters property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link LookupInstances.LookupParameters }
     *     
     */
    public void setLookupParameters(LookupInstances.LookupParameters value) {
        this.lookupParameters = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="lookupParameter">
     *           &lt;complexType>
     *             &lt;complexContent>
     *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *                 &lt;attribute name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
     *               &lt;/restriction>
     *             &lt;/complexContent>
     *           &lt;/complexType>
     *         &lt;/element>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "lookupParameter"
    })
    public static class LookupParameters {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected LookupInstances.LookupParameters.LookupParameter lookupParameter;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the lookupParameter property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link LookupInstances.LookupParameters.LookupParameter }
         *     
         */
        public LookupInstances.LookupParameters.LookupParameter getLookupParameter() {
            return lookupParameter;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the lookupParameter property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link LookupInstances.LookupParameters.LookupParameter }
         *     
         */
        public void setLookupParameter(LookupInstances.LookupParameters.LookupParameter value) {
            this.lookupParameter = value;
        }


        /**
         * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
         * 
         * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
         * 
         * <pre>
         * &lt;complexType>
         *   &lt;complexContent>
         *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
         *       &lt;attribute name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
         *     &lt;/restriction>
         *   &lt;/complexContent>
         * &lt;/complexType>
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         */
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "")
        public static class LookupParameter {

            @XmlAttribute
            protected String name;

            /**
             * Gets the value of the name property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the name property.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public void setName(String value) {
                this.name = value;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Unmarshal Code :

```
    public LookupInstances unmarshallXmlRequest(String xmlReq)
    {
        LookupInstances instances = null;
           try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( LookupInstances.class );
               Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
               StringBuffer xmlStr = new StringBuffer( xmlReq );
               StringReader strReader = new StringReader( xmlStr.toString() );
               StreamSource strSource = new StreamSource(strReader);
               Object o = u.unmarshal( strSource );
               instances = (LookupInstances)o;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return instances;
    }
```

I got this error :

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1", local:"lookupInstances"). Expected elements are <{}lookupInstances>
```

**Please help.**

Answer (score 20):

Below is some information that should help:

**XML**

Below is a portion of your XML.  One thing to note is the `xmlns` attribute.  This is a special attribute and refers to namespace qualification within the XML document.

```
<lookupInstances xmlns='http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1' name='LKIMGR'>
    <lookupParameters/>
</lookupInstances>
```

Below is another version of the XML with the same namespace qualification:

```
<abc:lookupInstances xmlns:abc='http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1' name='LKIMGR'>
    <abc:lookupParameters/>
</abc:lookupInstances>
```

When you remove the `xmlns` attribute the namespace qualification is removed.  The document below is not equivalent to the two above.

```
<lookupInstances name='LKIMGR'>
    <lookupParameters/>
</lookupInstances>
```

**Your Error**

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1", local:"lookupInstances"). Expected elements are <{}lookupInstances>
```

This error indicates that you have not mapped the namespace qualification correctly.

**Mapping the Namesapce Qualification in JAXB**

Namespace qualification in JAXB is done using the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.  Package level annotations go in `package-info.java`.  Below is the complete source for this class.  If you already have a `package-info.java` source file ensure it is being compiled and packaged with the rest of your classes.

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package your_package;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**XML Schema**

If you are generating your model from an XML Schema make sure this namespace qualification is properly define there.  It will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1" 
    xmlns="http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: That helped a lot Blaise. I was wondering how the app is working without mentioning namespace qualification in Java class, but as you explained it was package-info.java which was having that info.    In my first attempt I got the xsd file wrong which dragged me into an incorrect Jaxb class. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any way to supply the xmlns URI from a properties file ? For me the xmlns URI need to change dynamically for test and production environments

Comment: @XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) package your_package;
    
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema; 

This part is very important for JAXB generated classes, especially `elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` will not automatically be added by the JAXB. 
Thanks Blaise, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 9):

Change

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "lookupInstances")
```

to

```
@XmlRootElement( namespace = "http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1", name = "lookupInstances")
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the class created by JAXB does not contain the namespace information:

```
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "lookupParameters"
})
```

I suspect that it causes this error, simply because it expects no namespace:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1", local:"lookupInstances"). **Expected elements are <{}lookupInstances>**

I am not sure why the generated class lacks this information, but I would start with adding it manually to verify that this is the problem:

```
@XmlType(name = "", namespace= "http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1", propOrder = {
    "lookupParameters"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply @Magnilex.  As you suggested I added the namespace in java class declaration and the error vanished. But while unmarshaling the java class, it does not contain all elements or not properly initialised. I changed the jaxb class which now contains List to capture **lookupParameter** and It is working now.

Comment: @Rana Glad to help, and good that my answer pushed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the jaxb class by changing the xsd and it is working now.

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2015.01.13 at 03:49:52 PM IST 
//


package com.dsths.ga.awd.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="lookupParameters">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element name="lookupParameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
 *                     &lt;complexType>
 *                       &lt;simpleContent>
 *                         &lt;extension base="&lt;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>string">
 *                           &lt;attribute name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *                         &lt;/extension>
 *                       &lt;/simpleContent>
 *                     &lt;/complexType>
 *                   &lt;/element>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "lookupParameters"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "lookupInstances")
public class LookupInstances {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected LookupInstances.LookupParameters lookupParameters;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the lookupParameters property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link LookupInstances.LookupParameters }
     *     
     */
    public LookupInstances.LookupParameters getLookupParameters() {
        return lookupParameters;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the lookupParameters property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link LookupInstances.LookupParameters }
     *     
     */
    public void setLookupParameters(LookupInstances.LookupParameters value) {
        this.lookupParameters = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="lookupParameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
     *           &lt;complexType>
     *             &lt;simpleContent>
     *               &lt;extension base="&lt;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>string">
     *                 &lt;attribute name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
     *               &lt;/extension>
     *             &lt;/simpleContent>
     *           &lt;/complexType>
     *         &lt;/element>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "lookupParameter"
    })
    public static class LookupParameters {

        protected List<LookupInstances.LookupParameters.LookupParameter> lookupParameter;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the lookupParameter property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the lookupParameter property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getLookupParameter().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link LookupInstances.LookupParameters.LookupParameter }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<LookupInstances.LookupParameters.LookupParameter> getLookupParameter() {
            if (lookupParameter == null) {
                lookupParameter = new ArrayList<LookupInstances.LookupParameters.LookupParameter>();
            }
            return this.lookupParameter;
        }


        /**
         * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
         * 
         * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
         * 
         * <pre>
         * &lt;complexType>
         *   &lt;simpleContent>
         *     &lt;extension base="&lt;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>string">
         *       &lt;attribute name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
         *     &lt;/extension>
         *   &lt;/simpleContent>
         * &lt;/complexType>
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         */
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "value"
        })
        public static class LookupParameter {

            @XmlValue
            protected String value;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
            protected String name;

            /**
             * Gets the value of the value property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the value property.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public void setValue(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            /**
             * Gets the value of the name property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the name property.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public void setName(String value) {
                this.name = value;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to check the input XML file. 
Make sure the input XML should have the same root element as your XSD             file(Which you have used to create the JAXb classes)
So please try below XML, It will work fine :)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<lookupInstances name='LKIMGR'>
<lookupParameters>
<lookupParameter name='businessArea'>PQAA</lookupParameter>
<lookupParameter name='MEMBERNUMBER'>ANTHONY1900</lookupParameter>
</lookupParameters>
</lookupInstances>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.pqr.com/awd/rest/v1", 
elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) package your_package;

        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

This part is very important for JAXB generated classes, especially `elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` will not automatically be added by the JAXB.

Thanks Blaise, your answer helped me.